# Blocking RDP connections from secondary IP addresses

Tags: ip, rdp, blocking

I have a webserver running Windows 2008 R2 with multiple IPs assigned to it. I want to be able to RDP to the box via the main IP assigned to the box but not from any of the secondary IPs (ie... the websites IPs). I assume if I had control of the Firewall I could shut off the RDP port to the secondary IPs but it's in a hosted environment and I don't have access to the firewall. I'll contact the host to see if that's available but was hoping there was a setting I could set on the machine itself to not resolve RDP requests from the additional IPs.

Any advice?

Comment: You can select which network adapter is used by going to Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration, double clicking on RDP-TCP, and going to the Network adapter tab, but it does not limit multiple IPs on a single NIC.

Answer (score 2):

Like Jacob said, you can specify the network interfaces for which the rule for incoming RDP connections should be allowed. But this requires that each of your IP's are bound to a different interface:

Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound Rules -> Remote Desktop (TCP-in) -> Advanced -> Interface Types

Another way is to use the local scope:

Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound Rules -> Remote Desktop (TCP-in) -> Advanced -> Scope -> Local IP Address